django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DPY-4027: no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora in my dockerized django application
I am trying to connect my django application with an oracle database in vain.
I added the TNS_ADMIN environment variable but the problem persists.
Here is the content of my tnsnames.ora file:
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\HP\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

It should be noted that I use SQL developer.
My database configuration in django:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        'USER': os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        'HOST': os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        'POSRT': os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DB_PASS")
    }
}

docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: bdr-backend
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations --noinput &&
      python manage.py migrate --noinput && 
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
    container_name: redis2
    expose:
      - 6379

I use docker docker desktop on windows 10.
How to solve this problem?

Use the Easy Connect connection string syntax.  Set the settings.py "NAME" value to this.
A sample settings.py configuration file would be like:
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'xxxx:1521/xe',
    'USER': 'scott',
    'PASSWORD': 'topSecret'
  }
}

The xxxx will be your redacted hostname, or perhaps 'localhost'. With this syntax, you don't need a tnsnames.ora file, and you don't need to set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable.
Django gives preference to using python-oracledb. If python-oracledb is not found then cx_Oracle will be used. Settings are the same for these new and old drivers.
See Django 5.0 supports python-oracledb natively and Using python-oracledb 1.0 with SQLAlchemy, Pandas, Django and Flask.
Also, plan to update from 21x XE to 23ai Free, which you can get from the Oracle Database Software Downloads page.
